# What is this aircraft that appeared at Oshkosh 2017?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

This photo is an image from a youtube video of Oshkosh 2017. [image]

Comment: Clearly, it's a stealth bomber. Good disguise.

Comment: Where is the other half?

Comment: If you took that image, you should add it to the wikipedia article linked below.  Their picture only has half of the plane in it.

Answer (score 42):

That would be the [Boeing YL-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_L-15_Scout) a scout plane of which only 12 were built.

[Here](https://www.eaa.org/en/airventure/eaa-airventure-news-and-multimedia/eaa-airventure-news/eaa-airventure-oshkosh/07-29-2017-yl-15-slowly-reached-for-the-sky) is the EAA's article about the airplane from the airshow.

Comment: "Brunquist, paid \$800 in February 1954 for the example now at AirVenture. The airframe had 400 hours total when the elder Brunquist acquired it." Wow. Granted, that's about \$7,300 in today's dollars, but still. I wish airplanes with 400 frame hours were that cheap today...